# I get the feeling that Microsoft and Mac use two different forms of AES

Tags: aes, macos, .net, ruby

I have an AES string being produced with this class, [the AesCryptoServiceProvider Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider.aspx) provided by Microsoft.

And I need to decode this encryption with [Ruby's SSL::Cipher class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html) .

The problem is that if one encrypts one with one, you can't decrypt it with the other.

An example of my VB.NET code :

```
Private Const AesIV As String = "!QAZ2WSX#EDC4RFV"
Private Const AesKey As String = "5TGB&YHN7UJM(IK<"
aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC
aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
aes.BlockSize = 128
aes.KeySize = 128
```

Which produces this string :

```
p6SI3+hMRFRsQG5Vk+R1YdXv9EaCsfAuB0ZSsqkBcy83ki20U0bV5TZrwxJ0C4dlpSEJDwc7b5znd/8UNXEhcXV0m8tAms3lp4ZS2aUaSfc=
```

And then my ruby code does this :

```
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES128.new :CBC
# ^ That's 128 bit block in CBC mode, it defaults to 128 key size
cipher.iv = "!QAZ2WSX#EDC4RFV"
cipher.key = "5TGB&YHN7UJM(IK<"

solution = cipher.update("p6SI3+hMRFRsQG5Vk+R1YdXv9EaCsfAuB0ZSsqkBcy83ki20U0bV5TZrwxJ0C4dlpSEJDwc7b5znd/8UNXEhcXV0m8tAms3lp4ZS2aUaSfc=")

> "\xAC\xF3J{Cw\x95\xD8\x0F'\xC2\xB4,\xF2\x8E\xFE\xC9\x95\xD7\xE6JcB7\v\xBA\xD8kP'\a\x80\x81\x00\xC1\xCC\xE4\x95\x9E_5Ws\xF9j\xDF\xAC\xBA\"K\xF2\xB7,\x7F4\n\r\xB2\xF5\xC7R\xCFn\x97B\x05\\\xE70\\\x11x\xFA\v\xA2k\xBE(\x1E\xEB*O$\xDCc\xD7\xBEfs\x99\xADD\xC0\x1F\xBB9"   

solution << cipher.final

> OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError: wrong final block length
```

Comment: Does OpenSSL default to PKCS7 padding, or do you need to specify it?

Comment: @atk I *believe* it defaults to PKCS7, but I heard that PKCS5 and 7 are interchangeable. The only difference that PKCS7 can handle 64 bit blocks, but would still parse 5 the same.

Answer (score 3):

There are several weird things in your setup:

- ECB mode does not use any IV. You should not specify an IV when using ECB mode. Or, rather, you should not use ECB, which is weak (generally speaking).
- AES processes binary input, produces binary output, and uses a binary key. There is no character string whatsoever in AES; thus, any notion of encoding like UTF-8 should be completely irrelevant and out of scope. If you need to specify an encoding, then this means that there is some character string which is converted to bytes or back, and that can be a source of your problems.
- What you call "bit size" is obscure. A bit is a bit. Maybe you mean "block size". AES uses blocks of 128 bits, always.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Can I assume then that the key should also be ASCII-8bit as well?

Comment: Keys are not ASCII, keys are not UTF-8, keys are not _text_. Keys are bits. A key for AES is a sequence of 128, 192 or 256 bits, commonly represented in the memory of a computer as 16, 24 or 32 bytes, respectively (because most computers nowadays manage bits by groups of 8 bits, called precisely _octets_, and loosely referred to as "bytes").

Comment: Hmm.. strange. I posted above my code.. I would imagine this could be reproducible anywhere. Does it look like I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: Your code is using character strings everywhere, while AES uses binary sequences, so there are implicit or explicit conversions at various places. Chances are that these conversion don't happen the way you believe they do, and don't happen identically across languages either.

Comment: By character strings, you mean stuff that looks like Base64 as opposed to `"D\xA8\xC7\e\xC3\t@\x11\x9C\x1C\xA3L"` which is 8bit?